# Extensions fail to install or update / can't find a valid session key

Tags: wordpress, extension, session

I'm unable to download a new extension or update existing ones from the UI. I click on a 'Download' or 'Install' link, and then confirm it on the detail page. Then fairly quickly it returns to the extension page, but nothing has changed. The extension has not been installed. There's no error, nothing in the browser console, nothing in debug.log or ConfigAndLog. However, if I manually download the .zip file into the extensions directory, refresh the list, and click install, it will install the extension. I checked the permissions on the directories and they look fine. Anyway if it were a permissions problem surely it would pop an error up. I'd appreciate any suggestions. This is on Civi 5.58.1, Wordpress 6.2.2, PHP 7.4.33. Also tested a copy of the site on Civi 5.63.1 and PHP 8.1.2 with the same result.
**Edit with new information:** this may be related to the fact that clicking save on any Civicrm admin screen results in "Error type: Could not find a valid session key." I have double checked the CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL, WP_HOME, WP_SITEURL, etc. and they are all the same. The site continues to run and Civimail is sending out pre-scheduled emails, but I can't make any admin changes.

Comment: One easy thing to check: Is everything https or is there a mix of http and https?

Comment: It's all https.

Comment: Other things I've tried: I deactivated my caching plugin, W3 Total Cache. I temporarily deactivated WordFence long enough to test again. No change.

Comment: I found a partial answer. There appears to be a conflict between Civicrm and Tickera. I found that when Civi begins coughing up session key errors, I can fix it by deactivating Tickera. However the original issue about not being able to make extension changes via the UI remains. I can live with that mystery for the moment using CV on the command line.